# COALESCE Joins in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, break, coalesce

I am trying to join several arrays in Javascript with some kind of "COALESCE" function like in SQL.

Below are my arrays:

```
var items = [
    {itemid: 'A'},
    {itemid: 'B'},
    {itemid: 'C'},
    {itemid: 'D'},
    {itemid: 'E'}
];

var specials = [
    {itemid: 'A', price: '5.00'},
    {itemid: 'C', price: '5.00'},
    {itemid: 'E', price: '5.00'}
];

var mainprices = [
    {itemid: 'A', price: '10.00'},
    {itemid: 'B', price: '10.00'},
    {itemid: 'C', price: '10.00'},
    {itemid: 'D', price: '10.00'},
    {itemid: 'E', price: '10.00'}
];
```

What I want is :
My first column to be **itemid**
My second column to be **prices**

I want the price column to retrieve prices from my '**specials**' array first, and then for the rows that have no values to return prices from my '**mainprices**' array.

Here is what I have tried so far :

```
var results = [];
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    var found = false;
    for (var j=0; j<specials.length; j++) {
        if (items[i].itemid === specials[j].itemid) {
            results.push({
                item_id: items[i].itemid, 
                price_value: specials[j].price
            });
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found === false) {
        results.push({
            item_id: items[i].itemid, 
            price_value: null
        });    
    }
}

console.log(results);
```

This outputs :

```
[{item_id: "A", price_value: "5.00"}, {item_id: "B", price_value: null}, {item_id: "C", price_value: "5.00"}, {item_id: "D", price_value: null}, {item_id: "E", price_value: "5.00"}]
```

What I would like to do now is to replace null values with '**mainprices.price**' values

I would really appreciate if someone could help me !!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.map` the `mainPrices` array, and search for a matching element in `specials`:

```js
var items = [
    {itemid: 'A'},
    {itemid: 'B'},
    {itemid: 'C'},
    {itemid: 'D'},
    {itemid: 'E'}
];

var specials = [
    {itemid: 'A', price: '5.00'},
    {itemid: 'C', price: '5.00'},
    {itemid: 'E', price: '5.00'}
];

var mainprices = [
    {itemid: 'A', price: '10.00'},
    {itemid: 'B', price: '10.00'},
    {itemid: 'C', price: '10.00'},
    {itemid: 'D', price: '10.00'},
    {itemid: 'E', price: '10.00'}
];

const pricesWithSpecials = mainprices.map(({ itemid, price }) => {
  const found = specials.find((e) => e.itemid === itemid);
  return { itemid, price: found ? found.price : price };
});
console.log(pricesWithSpecials);
```

Or, for `O(N)` complexity instead of `O(N^2)` complexity, map the `specials` to their `itemid`s first:

```js
var items = [
    {itemid: 'A'},
    {itemid: 'B'},
    {itemid: 'C'},
    {itemid: 'D'},
    {itemid: 'E'}
];

var specials = [
    {itemid: 'A', price: '5.00'},
    {itemid: 'C', price: '5.00'},
    {itemid: 'E', price: '5.00'}
];

var mainprices = [
    {itemid: 'A', price: '10.00'},
    {itemid: 'B', price: '10.00'},
    {itemid: 'C', price: '10.00'},
    {itemid: 'D', price: '10.00'},
    {itemid: 'E', price: '10.00'}
];

const specialsByItemid = specials.reduce((a, item) => {
  a[item.itemid] = item;
  return a;
}, {});

const pricesWithSpecials = mainprices.map(({ itemid, price }) => {
  return { itemid, price: specialsByItemid[itemid] ? specialsByItemid[itemid].price : price };
});
console.log(pricesWithSpecials);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! I am fairly new to JavaScript. Your help is really appreciated. Have a great day !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by building a dictionary of `itemid` to `price`. To build the dictionary, list the prices in the same array, with the most important at the end, so they overwrite previous entries when building the dictionary.

From this dictionary, it is then easy to get the price for your `itemid` and you can generate your output by mapping over your items.

You can wrap this logic in a reusable function that takes as many price arrays as you want. You just have to feed these arrays by importance, with the most important to the right.

```js
const items = [
  {itemid: 'A'},
  {itemid: 'B'},
  {itemid: 'C'},
  {itemid: 'D'},
  {itemid: 'E'}
];

const specials = [
  {itemid: 'A', price: '5.00'},
  {itemid: 'C', price: '5.00'},
  {itemid: 'E', price: '5.00'}
];

const mainprices = [
  {itemid: 'A', price: '10.00'},
  {itemid: 'B', price: '10.00'},
  {itemid: 'C', price: '10.00'},
  {itemid: 'D', price: '10.00'},
  {itemid: 'E', price: '10.00'}
];

const superImportantPrices = [
  {itemid: 'B', price: '15.00'}
];

const coalesce = (items, ...prices) => {
  const pricesDict = prices.flat().reduce((acc, { itemid, price }) => {
    acc[itemid] = price;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return items.map(({ itemid }) => ({ itemid, price: pricesDict[itemid] }));
}

// call coalesce with the most important prices to the right
const result = coalesce(items, mainprices, specials, superImportantPrices);

console.log(result);
```